# get content from random path json

Tags: php, json

i have json respons like this

```
"query": {
    "pages": {
      "24658": {
        "pageid": 24658,
        "content": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
               }
             }
         }
```

I want to take part "content", but parts after "pages" are always changing and only changed in numerical form. if i just use json_decode it just seems impossible

I have tried to use the code below

```
<?php
    $access = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://example.com"), TRUE);
    echo $access['query']['pages']['24658]['content'];
?>
```

But, the script above will only work once, and as I said before, that part after pages always change randomly, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please include your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first index using `key()`:

```
$id = key($access['query']['pages']); /* must give you 24658 here */
$content = $access['query']['pages'][$id];
echo $content
```